# Not able to understand migration file for Crowdsale in ERC20

Tags: solidity, truffle, erc-20, javascript, truffle-migration

I am trying to understand nuts and bolts of the simple CrowdSales in ERC20.

In the simplest way, we have a smart contract that mint the fixed number of tokens (SimpleToken) and then we have the crowdsale (SimpleCrowdsale) contract that is in charge to allow accounts to have tokens in exchange of eth.
So far so good, but when we write the migration file in truffle

```
const SimpleToken = artifacts.require("SimpleToken");
const SimpleCrowdsale = artifacts.require("SimpleCrowdsale");

module.exports = async function (deployer, network, accounts) {
  await deployer.deploy(SimpleToken, 'Simple Token', 'SIM', '10000000000000000000000');
  const token = await SimpleToken.deployed();
  
  await deployer.deploy(SimpleCrowdsale, 1, accounts[0], token.address);
  const crowdsale = await SimpleCrowdsale.deployed();

  token.transfer(crowdsale.address, await token.totalSupply())
};
```

I have a problem understanding what does the following line

```
await deployer.deploy(SimpleCrowdsale, 1, accounts[0], token.address);
```

To me it seems that we have to provide the token address (where the SimpleToken sits) and then the address of the account that deploy the SimpleCrowdsale (accounts[0]) but in my understanding, these addresses are the same. If it is not, why we don't have the token.address in the account list? Where is the flaw in my reasoning?
Many thanks

Comment: Which version of the `SimpleCrowdsale` contract are you working with? If I'n not wrong one parameter is the wallet that will receive the ether payments, and the other is the token.

Comment: I went through this example https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/deploy-a-simple-erc20-token-in-remix/1203     So following your reasoning, if we minted the token in the other smart contract named simpleToken the token.address is referring to this address. I am right?

Comment: `token.address` should be the address where SimpleToken was deployed. But I'm not sure it works as expected, in old truffle versions `SimpleToken.deployed()` didn't return the correct value inside the migration script that creates SimpleToken. You have to use `SimpleToken.address` instead.

Comment: Ok I have to check this very last point but I would like to be sure that in the constructor of SimpleCrowdsale I have to provide the info about the smart contract address that creates/owns the token. So in this version of OpenZeppelin SimpleCrowdsale they decided to keep separated the minter of  these token from the smart contract that manage the sale of them in exc of ETH.

Comment: Check the Crowdsale documentation, the parameters used to be well documented in the constructor. As I said previously one address is the wallet that will receive the ethers from the token sale, and the other is ERC20 token address.